# Fluid running into invisible wall

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So i'm trying to make a fluid simulation where the fluid runs in a glass pipe and falls out. My problem is it doesn't fall out, it hits an invisible wall at the end of the pipe. 
The obstacle is set to shell, i am in cycles render and everything seems to be fine. Does anyone know why it's doing that?

Comment: just guessing, but have you checked that is not a caching issue or a "not applied" scaling issue of some fluid sim component?

Comment: How do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Invisible wall? Are you sure it isn't just the fluid domain?

Check your other layers. It's possible one of them has an object in it that is interacting across multiple layers and influencing your fluid sim even though it's not on the same layer.

Also try pressing alt h to unhide all objects. Try setting the obstacle to volume only. Test these out by baking at a low res so you know it would work with a higher res.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Blender 2.78b. I worked with a wax simulation. After the bake there was visible that the wax was blocked by an invisible obstacle. I checked everything: other layers, unhiding all objects, recreating domain object from scratch but the problem wasn't solved.

Finally I perceived that the invisible obstacle appears exactly on the X axis. I moved all objects above that axis and then the wax simulation started working flawlessly.